# "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema in .. Magento PWA

Tags: magento, progressive-web-apps

Next Exception: Report ID: graph-ql-650960cb9cc09; Message: Config element "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema in /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Exception/ExceptionFormatter.php:64 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/module-graph-ql/Controller/GraphQl.php(199): Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\ExceptionFormatter->create() #1 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl->dispatch() #2 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->___callParent() #3 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(75): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #4 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() #5 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #6 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/generated/code/Magento/GraphQl/Controller/GraphQl/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->___callPlugins() #7 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->dispatch() #8 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #9 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() #10 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: graph-ql-650960cb9cc09; Message: Config element "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema at /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Exception/ExceptionFormatter.php:64) [previous exception] [object] (LogicException(code: 0): Config element "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema at /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Config.php:57)"} []

**I was facing this issue when i am setup Magento PWA in my local: **

Next Exception: Report ID: graph-ql-650960cb9cc09; Message: Config element "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema in /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Exception/ExceptionFormatter.php:64 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/module-graph-ql/Controller/GraphQl.php(199): Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\ExceptionFormatter->create() #1 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl->dispatch() #2 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->___callParent() #3 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(75): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #4 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() #5 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #6 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/generated/code/Magento/GraphQl/Controller/GraphQl/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->___callPlugins() #7 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl\Interceptor->dispatch() #8 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #9 /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() #10 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: graph-ql-650960cb9cc09; Message: Config element "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema at /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Exception/ExceptionFormatter.php:64) [previous exception] [object] (LogicException(code: 0): Config element "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema at /var/www/html/pwatest/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Config.php:57)"} []

Answer (score 2):

Please enable flowing modules from Magento root:

php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Magento_EavGraphQlAux Magento_CatalogGraphQlAux Magento_PageBuilderPwa Magento_ReCaptchaGraphQlPwa Magento_ReCaptchaPwa Magento_SalesGraphQlAux Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQlPwa Magento_WeeeGraphQlAux